# Ubuntu .desktop links and absolute referencing

Tags: ubuntu, hyperlink

In /usr/share/applications/ there are many desktop files. Here is an example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=eclipse
Exec=eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

I don't understand why it doesn't have something like:

```
Location=/usr/lib/eclipseEE/eclipse
```

As without this, how does the Ubuntu know which eclipse to run if there are more than one?
Tutorials keep pointing to these .Desktop files, which don't seem to point to specific executables.

***veterans please stop reading***

For the glorious benefit of complete beginners: To view a list of your .Desktop files, press ctrl+alt+T to open a terminal. Type "cd /" to change directory to root, type "cd usr/share/applications" to change directory to where the links (shortcuts) are apparently located (They are also located in "/home/*yourusername*/.local/share/applications", the unity menu will display links from both, it depends if you want to have the link for just your login, in case you put programs in your home folder, or whether you want to make the link available for other users. If you're the only user it doesn't matter). Type "ls" (LS) to list all files. To edit, say, "eclipse.Desktop" type "sudo nano eclipse.Desktop", give password if asked, then you can edit. "^" means the control key, there is a list of commands at the bottom for save etc. To create an entry, "sudo nano newname.Desktop" and it will make one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "Exec" line...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eeeclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=eclipse
Exec=/usr/lib/eeeclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
Comment[en_GB]=Eeeclipse Integrated Development Environment
```

Ubuntu assumes that things are in "/usr/lib/*look_in_ALL_the_folders*" and will ratch around for it... specify exactly where to avoid problems.

THE HOLY GRAIL OF MAKING SHORTCUTS:

```
sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new
```

This one command, will create a link which will appear when you search unity launcher (ubuntu start menu) 0_0
Make sure that for 'command', you type in "/usr/lib/teh_folder/application_executable" (or browse to it). If it doesn't work, install:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

Noob note: The lines beginning "sudo" give root (admin) permission, and its inferred you type those commands into a terminal (and press enter. ctrl+alt+t to open a terminal in ubuntu. Ctrl+shift+V to paste into ubuntu terminal).